# Is Figure tag adequate for site logo

Tags: html

This can be the markup but I don't know whether it's semantically correct

```
<figure class="logo">
    <a href="http://sitios/julioverne">
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>Brand Name</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: I don't really know. For me, a *figure* is an illustration within the text of a document. I'm not sure whether I would consider a logo a figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `figure` element represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning.

Seems fitting for a logo to me.

([reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figure.html))

Comment: Logos are not referenced from the main flow of the document.

Comment: @Cmorales Your point being? Are you arguing that since they are not referenced from the main flow, removing them _would_ affect the document's meaning? The main point of the cited paragraph is that the `figure` can be moved away without affecting the meaning, not that it _must be possible_ to remove the `figure` from the main flow.

Comment: Actually no, my point is that a logo has no meaning at all in the document, it's purely presentational, though a figure isn't. Please take a look at the link that I put in my answer below. A logo wouldn't make sense in an appendix in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the definition that @lanzz provided looks like a good fit, a logo shouldn't be a figure, according to this:

http://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.png

Figures are meant for content referenced in the document, like in a text book about anatomy that explains where your heart is located and it tells you to "look at Figure 1". Logos are not referenced like that in websites, they are purely presentational.

Comment: `html5doctor.com` is not an authoritative source for the semantics of the `figure` element. Even if it were, I'd say the "moved to an appendix" is more of an example scenario, not the intended semantics of the element itself.

Comment: Fair point. The problem with the new tags is that they are too ambiguous sometimes, it's too open to interpretation :S

Comment: By your reasoning, all images should go in figures because allmost all can moved away from the document without affecting its meaning.